# mongodb replica-set kubernetes read queries serivce

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have created a 3 node cluster, with 3 physical machines in the same network. I have created some persistent volumes and one storage class with this code:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: localstorage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer



---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local1-1pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes1
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local1-2pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes1
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local1-3pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol3
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes1
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local2-1pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes2
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local2-2pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes2
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local2-3pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol3
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes2
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local3-1pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes3
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local3-2pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes3
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local3-3pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /mnt/disk/vol3
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubernetes3
---
```

Then i created my mongo instances, as stateful replica sets with this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongo

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app:  mongo
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        command:
        - mongod
        - "--replSet"
        - rs0
        - "--bind_ip_all"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
      storageClassName: "localstorage"
```

At first point i initialise my replica set with this command:

```
rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [
{ _id: 0, host : "mongo-0.mongo:27017" },
{ _id: 1, host : "mongo-1.mongo:27017" },
{ _id: 2, host : "mongo-2.mongo:27017" }
]});
```

So now what i am trying to do, is to create an extra service which will be responsible for reading queries. How can i achieve that? The best case scenario is my query to be served automaticaly by one of three replica sets. First check for primary and if it not available, get it from secandary replica. Is this easy?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/). Looks like all you need to do is to change `read-preference` from `primary` (default) to `primaryPrefered` in client library. Check you client library for details. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from mongodb secondary replicas (as an alternative when primary replica is not available) you don't need any special setup.

All you need to do is to change `read-preference` parameter from `primary` (default) to `primaryPrefered` in any mongodb client library you use (its supported in all of the official libriaries, I cannot guarantee this is supported in unofficial libs).

From docs:

> #### primaryPreferred
>
> In most situations, operations read from the primary but if it is unavailable, operations read from secondary members.

Check [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) if you want to read about othe possible values for read-preference paramater.